# htaccess rewrite conflict with https

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have the following rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ user_home.php?domain=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which works fine for rewriting my urls, but I now need to force HTTPS,so I am using this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Both work, but they do not work together.

`mysite.com/somepage` should redirect to `https://mysite.com/somepage`,

but instead it redirects to `https://mysite.com/user_home.php?domain=somepage`.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: What order do you have those 2 blocks in? HTTPS piece first or second?

Comment: i tried both ways, same result

Comment: Do you have separate vhosts for the http & https endpoints?

Comment: nope, same. on the url rewritei do not need https though, so is there a way to add that as a condition?

Comment: So you don't have separate `<VirtualHost>` blocks, like `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `<VirtualHost *:443>`? You might want to check the `AllowOverride` in both blocks to ensure the rewrites are actually happening on the HTTPS side. And yes, you can have a condition for the rewrite to only affect certain things, but looks like your trying to redirect everything to https?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me; I'm guessing your problem may be on the server configuration side or somewhere else perhaps. The rewrite rules are fine though AFAICT.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@crazysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All 
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@crazysite.com
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
</VirtualHost>
```

**/var/www/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ user_home.php?domain=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**/var/www/user_home.php**

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET['domain']);
```

Loading *http://crazysite.com/test* redirects to *https://crazysite.com/test* and the output on the page is

> string(4) "test"

Comment: the output page is correct, the only problem is that it displays in the url with the query string

Comment: Have you tried stripping it down to something simple like what I have posted in my answer? Sometimes it's good to get a minimal thing working and backtrack to see where the error is occurring in the real system.